# Flask web application 1st time

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pandas as pd
import re
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'xlsx'}

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

def load_excel_file():
    if os.path.isfile("abc.xlsx"):
        return pd.read_excel("abc.xlsx")
    else:
        return None

def process_comments(comments):
    result = {}
    ec_count = 0
    ic_count = 0
    names = []

    pattern = r'\[(.*?)\] (.*?) \((.*?)\) -'

    for comment in comments.split(';'):
        match = re.search(pattern, comment.strip())
        if match:
            date, name, role = match.groups()
            if role == "EC":
                ec_count += 1
            elif role == "IC":
                ic_count += 1
            names.append(name.split()[0])  

    result["count"] = ec_count + ic_count
    result["ec"] = ec_count
    result["ic"] = ic_count
    result["names"] = names

    return result

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])  # Allow only POST
def process_comments_route():
    excel_data = load_excel_file()
    
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
        data = request.get_json()
        job_id = data.get("Job Req ID")
        
        if excel_data is not None:
            row = excel_data[excel_data['Job Req ID'] == job_id]
            
            if not row.empty:
                comments = row['Comments'].iloc[0]  
                result = process_comments(comments)
                response = {job_id: result}
                return jsonify(response)
            else:
                return jsonify({"error": "Job ID not found in Excel file"}), 404
        else:
            return jsonify({"error": "Excel file not found"}), 404  # Return 404 Not Found if Excel file is missing
    else:
        return jsonify({"error": "Unsupported Media Type"}), 415  # Return 415 Unsupported Media Type status

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soEZ9.png)

I'm trying to run this code and it gives me the attached error. I know there are few errors, but I don't seem, to find it. Can you guys rectify? Appreciate your help, I have a data with 2 columns and I want to extract information and return in form of json.

Comment: You only allowed POST method, but you're trying to open the page in the browser, which sends a GET request.

Comment: I had tried that but it gives me KeyError: 'CONTENT_TYPE'

Answer (score 1):

The `"/"` route is set to only accept request sent with the [POST method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST).

When visiting an URL in the browser the request is sent with the [GET method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET).

Changing the method in `@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])` to GET instead `@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])` should fix the problem, if you wish to see the data in your browser.

Otherwise you can send a POST request using a tool like [cURL](https://reqbin.com/req/c-g5d14cew/curl-post-example) or [Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/).

Comment: I had tried that but it gives me KeyError: 'CONTENT_TYPE'